# rename directory by extracting file basename inside the the same directory

Tags: bash

Consider the paths:

```
    dir1/hs/pfg001G.onename.csv.bam
    dir1/hk/pfg001G.anothername.txt.ubam
    dir2/hs/pfg002T.secondname.fa.fz
    dir2/hk/pfg002T.heythere.txt
```

I would like to match the following pattern on the file name: `pfg[0-9]*[G-T]` or in words pfg followed by 3 numbers, followed by a G or T.

I tried the following command with `find` but it does not work.

`find . -type f -name 'pfg[0-9]*[G-T]'`

Instead this finds the whole filename:

`find . -type f -name 'pfg[0-9]*[G-T]*'`

My ultimate goal is to find this pattern from the parent `hs` directory only and rename `dir1` and `dir2` with the extracted pattern found in the filename. So as a result I would have the paths like that:

```
    pfg001G/hs/pfg001G.onename.csv.bam
    pfg001G/hk/pfg001G.anothername.txt.ubam
    pfg002T/hs/pfg002T.secondname.fa.fz
    pfg002T/hk/pfg002T.heythere.txt
```

I was attempting to solve this with `awk` and `xargs` but I don't know well how to approach this problem:

`echo */*/* | xargs -n 1 basename | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`

This command gets me the names `pfg001G` and `pfg002T`, I would need to rename `dir1` and `dir2` now. If someone has a more elegant way to solve this please write here.

Comment: RE: "followed by a G or T" -- Then `[G-T]` should be `[GT]` because as you have it, it's looking for `G` thru `T`, not just `G` or `T`.

Comment: Awk is a tool for manipulating text, the tool for manipulating files and processes is a shell. What you're trying to do has nothing to do with awk, please tag the question with whichever shell you use.

Comment: Try find with -regex as opposed to -name

Comment: alex, There is a discrepancy between your before and after naming in that you explicitly state "My ultimate goal is to find this pattern from the parent hs directory only and rename dir1 and dir2 with the extracted pattern found in the filename. So as a result I would have the paths like that:" yet you show directories with `hk` not just `hs` as you so state.  -- If you want "parent hs directory only" then fix your expected output. Please take some time and review what you said and what you show and clear up the discrepancy.

Comment: @user3439894 why is there a discrepancy since both `hs` and `hk` have its parent directory `dir1` ? If I rename `dir1` based on `hs`, `hk` is automatically renamed too because it's a child directory of `dir1` justs as `hs` . The only difference amond `hs` and `hk` is that the file extension of my target is different, and this might be an issue when addressing to clear the file extension from within `hs` or `hk`, for example with some regular expression.

Comment: Change _directory_ to where the e.g. `dir1`, `dir2` _subdirectory_ are, e.g `cd /path/to/directory` and then copy and paste the following _command_ and run it. It will just output what the `mv` _commands_ will look like. If you like how they look, remove the `echo` _command_ from in front of the `mv` _command_ and run it again to make the actual changes: `while IFS= read -r pathname; do filename="${pathname##*/}"; newdir="${filename%%.*}"; olddir="${pathname%%/*}"; echo mv -vn "$olddir" "$newdir"; done <<< "$(find * -type f -name 'pfg[0-9][0-9][0-9][GT]*' | grep '/hs/')"`

Comment: If you want to understand what it is doing then read the Shell Parameter Expansion section and the Command Substitution section of the Bash Reference Manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (untested) should work:

```
while IFS= read -r path; do
    fname="${path##*/}"
    olddir="${path%/*}"
    reldir="${olddir#*/}"
    newbase="${fname%%.*}"
    newdir="${newbase}/${reldir}"
    mkdir -p "$newdir" &&
    mv -- "$path" "$newdir"
done < <(find . -type f -name 'pfg[0-9]*[GT]*')
```

Comment: @EdMorton Hi Ed, honestly I don't understand your code, could you explain it please.

Comment: @alex - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to read the output of a command using a loop as I'm doing, and see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for how parameter expansion works which is everything else I'm doing. Also add `set -x` at the top of  the script before running it to see what values the various variables are being set to. Let me know if you have any questions after that.

Answer (score 1):

Associative arrays to the rescue. Their use make this solution a bit "easier", in that you don't need to use `uniq`.

First, extract the names (**side note:** if files in e.g. *dir1* have more names than just *pfg001G* this fails for obvious reasons.):

```
$ ls .
dir1   dir2
$ declare -A arr
$ while IFS= read -r i;do
    fil="${i##*/}"
    di="${i#*/}"
    arr["${di%%/*}"]="${fil%%.*}"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*pfg[0-9][0-9][0-9]*[GT]*")
```

Then rename the directories:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}";do mv "$i" "${arr[$i]}" ;done
```

This is a two step process just to avoid error messages from `mv`. They would trigger within a loop/pipe when trying to access an already renamed *dir1* or *dir2*.

Comment: files have more names in dir1, it's just a sample I provided

Comment: if files have more names, e.g. pfg012G pfg013G, how to choose the directory name? If all follow the same seach pattern and the number stays the same, changing just the string after the [GT], the solution works.